# Importing emails from Outlook to Excel from a specific time period

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I managed to create a macro that imports emails from Outlook to Excel, if the email subject is a specific string.

However, I also want to add a criteria to import only emails received between two dates, but I can't seem to find the right way to do it.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
For Each OutlookMail In IFolder.Items
    If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime >= Range("start_date").Value And OutlookMail.ReceivedTime <= Range("end_date").Value Then
        ar() = Split(OutlookMail.Body, ",")
            If InStr(OutlookMail.Subject, "Exportation of purchase order") > 0 Then
                For Each Item In ar
                    dbf.Range("A2").Offset(i, 0).Value = Split(Split(Item, ":")(0), "-")(0)
                    dbf.Range("A2").Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit
                    i = i + 1
                Next Item
            End If
    End If
Next OutlookMail
```

Right now, the code imports every email that has been received from the "start_date" until the last received email.

I'm probably messing up the order or something like that, but if anyone could help me, I'd appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

Your `If` statement looks OK although I can stare at code all day and miss some obvious error.  However, my first thought would be that the end date is not what you think it is.  Please, add the following code before the `For` loop:

```
  Dim StartDate As Date
  Dim EndDate As Date

  StartDate = Range("start_date").Value
  EndDate =  Range("end_date").Value

  Debug.Print "Date range is " & StartDate & " to " & EndDate
  Debug.Assert False
```

Execution will stop at `Debug.Assert False`.  Is the date range as you expect?

Comment: I managed to get it to work. I structered the code properly and while re-writing it, I realized that ReceivedTime outputs a Date/Time value instead of just a date, which was most likely what was preventing me from setting a time period since ReceivedTime and "start_date" and "end_date" wouldn't match at all. Thank you for your time and your help tho. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Barbaaz.  A date, a time and a date+time are all of type `Date` and can be compared without problems.  I do not understand how using `DateValue` can help.  Did you try my code?  Is `EndDate` what you think it is?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. To be honest I did not try your code. Since I was able to see the "end_date" value by hovering on it during debugging, I was able to check if the "end_date" value was the value that was set on that range. I'm not sure why it didn't work properly before I added DateValue, but it's working now. Thank you very much for your help and your time though.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I decided to try and re-write the code while structuring it properly and finally managed to get it to work as intended.

I don't know if anyone will have the same issue as me in the future, so I'll post the new code as an answer.

```
Sub GetDataFromOutlook()

    Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutlookNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim IFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim OutlookMail As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ar() As String
    ReDim ar(0 To i)

    Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set IFolder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("IMPORTADOS")
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    i = 0

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each OutlookMail In IFolder.Items
        If InStr(OutlookMail.Subject, "Exportation of purchase order") > 0 Then
            If DateValue(OutlookMail.ReceivedTime) >= DateValue(Range("start_date")) And DateValue(OutlookMail.ReceivedTime) <= DateValue(Range("end_date")) Then
                ar() = Split(OutlookMail.Body, ",")
                For Each Item In ar
                    ws.Range("A2").Offset(i, 0).Value = Split(Split(Item, ":")(0), "-")(0)
                    ws.Range("A2").Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit
                    i = i + 1
                Next Item
            End If
        End If
    Next OutlookMail

    ws.Range("Table1[#All]").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
    ws.Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Set IFolder = Nothing
    Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing

End Sub
```